# While Installing Ubuntu 15.04 need to know compatibility

Tags: ubuntu-15.04

I am trying to install **Ubuntu 15.04**. For that i downloaded Ubuntu 15.04 for Intel x86 version. Is that version suitable for my 64 bit Intel i7 processor. Also i would like to know if it is a stable version of Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

1. x86 (32-bit) applications or OS's are compatible with 64-bit processors. However, AMD64 (64-bit) applications or OS's are not compatible with 32-bit processors. **Your downloaded version of Ubuntu is compatible with your processor.**
2. **Yes, it is a stable version of Ubuntu**, but it's not LTS (Long Term Support).

EDIT: As DJCrashdummy said, you should definitely install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu on your PC to achieve the maximum performance.

Also,

> if you don't want to upgrade every 6-9 months you should take the latest LTS-version (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: but i would advise you to install a 64bit-version on a 64bit-system! -- and if you don't want to upgrade every 6-9 months you should take the latest LTS-version (Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: Why the downvote? OP was asking about compatibility…

Comment: the downvote wasn't me! with the "extensions" i had given the same answer... (although i can't even downvote cause of to less reputation!) -- i just flagged the question "should be moved to https://askubuntu.com/"...

Comment: I didn't say iz was you, I'm just disappointed.

Comment: @redbeam_: 64-bit version definitely has advantages, but if he has 4GB RAM or less he's unlikely to benefit much from it.